# Scroll vertically 100% on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I need an animated scroll effect that pushes the site down for 100%. It's basically a multipage in one website and each 100%, there is a different site. I understand that there are multiple plugins for this, but I'd like to get this to work manually.

I tried using anchors and IDs to stimulate the 100% scrolling effect, but I can't think of a pure solution that moves the page down 100% without some sort of help from other IDs or classes.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: May i ask why using anchors is not good?

Comment: I cannot rely on that solution because they target ID might not be positioned 100% from the top each time and the end of the site is unknown... It could go down for I don't know how long and I need a more flexible way of handling this.

Comment: Ah, i didnt realize that the end was unknown. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, its pretty simple, use the below snippet which will help you achieve what you are looking for...

```
$("a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //Prevent default action of anchor
    $("html, body").animate({ 
        scrollTop: $(document).height()  //Get the document height
    }, "slow"); //Animates the scroll
    /* Can also use 3000, 4000 i.e 3 seconds, 4 seconds to animate the scroll */
});
```

Here, `onclick` of the `<a>` tag, we first prevent the default action of the anchor tag, and then on click, we animate the scroll upto the bottom of the document.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hab5qst4/1/)

Note: Use an `id` or a `class` for the anchor tag you are looking to attach the `onclick` evebt on, as the current selector am using is general one and will target all the anchor tags in your document.